# Sum-of-squares quartic polynomials in three variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals, real-algebraic-geometry, sum-of-squares-method

Suppose $f \in \mathbb R [x,y,z]$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $4$. Furthermore, suppose we can write

$$f(x,y,z)=\sum_i p_i(x,y,z)^2$$ where each $p_i$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$. My question:

> Is there any "clean" intuition for the set of degree-$4$ $f$'s that can be written this way?

For example, if restriction $f$ to the unit sphere, do its maxima or minima have any relationships to one another?  How do we distinguish this set from the full set of degree-$4$ homogeneous polynomials?

I know this question is vague.  I'm trying to get an intuition for the "sum of squares" (SOS) condition in this case.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition is that $f \ge 0$ on $\mathbb R^3$.  See [Polynomial SOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_SOS).  This is one of the few cases where every non-negative form can be represented as a sum of squares.

Comment: Interesting!  Definitely a start.  I'm hoping we can say something geometric about $f$, e.g. that it has some symmetry when evaluated over the unit sphere or that the maxima/minima occur in orthogonal directions similar to eigenvalue problems.

Comment: Indeed it is!  Can we say anything about this subset? :-)

(Thanks for editing the post to have nicer formatting!)

Comment: A little more progress:  In fact $f$ is the sum of *three* squares.  See http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~scheider/preprints/hilberttq.pdf